# How to keep all linux kernel packages on Kubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, kubuntu

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 on my private laptop. When the package system updates my Linux kernel it removes the old packages, only keeping the 2 newest versions of the kernel images (and associated packages). At the moment that would be (AFAIR) 3.13.0-32 and 3.13.0-48. How do I get the package system to stop removing the old kernel images?

I realize this will leave me with a long list of not used kernel images, but I would rather have to do the clean up myself, than risk ending up in a situation where I can't boot my laptop.

EDIT: Based on the answer from Aaron Digulla I created a file, `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99keep-kernels`, with this content:

```
APT::NeverAutoRemove
{
   "^linux-image-*-generic$";
   "^linux-image-*-generic$";
   "^linux-headers-*-generic$";
   "^linux-headers-*-generic$";
   "^linux-image-extra-*-generic$";
   "^linux-image-extra-*-generic$";
   "^linux-signed-image-*-generic$";
   "^linux-signed-image-*-generic$";
   "^kfreebsd-image-*-generic$";
   "^kfreebsd-image-*-generic$";
   "^kfreebsd-headers-*-generic$";
   "^kfreebsd-headers-*-generic$";
   "^gnumach-image-*-generic$";
   "^gnumach-image-*-generic$";
   "^.*-modules-*-generic$";
   "^.*-modules-*-generic$";
   "^.*-kernel-*-generic$";
   "^.*-kernel-*-generic$";
   "^linux-backports-modules-.*-generic$";
   "^linux-backports-modules-.*-generic$";
   "^linux-tools-*-generic$";
   "^linux-tools-*-generic$";
};
```

But that didn't work. Ubuntu still only keeps the 2 latest kernels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pinning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) won't work for you since it will prevent from upgrading kernels altogether.

Look into `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove` and `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels`. These files contain lists of packages which should be purged automatically. The second file is maintained by the script `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal`

To solve your problem, copy the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels` into `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99keep-kernels` and edit the patterns to match any version of the 11 packages in there.

So

```
"^linux-image-3\.13\.0-45-generic$";
```

would become

```
"^linux-image-";
```

This pattern now matches any version of the package and prevents `apt` from deleting them ever. The post-install script does the same thing which doesn't create a conflict - your version of the file simply matches more packages and prevents any version to be deleted automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand how simply copying the file, without changing anything would work. But I have done it, and now I'm waiting for the next kernel update from Ubuntu to see what will happen.

I would have upvoted your answer, but because I'm new on this site, I don't have the reputation to do that yet. I will try to remember to come back here later, when I can upvote your answer.

Comment: I've tried to clarify my answer. Have a look.

Comment: I get at least part of it now. :-) But I'm still confused, because the line at the start (APT::NeverAutoRemove) seems to say "Don't delete", even for the 01autoremove-kernels file. Am I completely missing the point, or maybe being ovberly literal?

A second question? Do you know what the $-sign at the end of the original lines mean?

Comment: And also: Shouldn't there be some kind of wildcard in the lines in the 99keep-kernels file? Or is that implied?

These lines in the 01autoremove-kernels file seem to imply the need for wildcards:
   "^.*-modules-3\.13\.0-32-generic$";
   "^.*-modules-3\.13\.0-48-generic$";
   "^.*-kernel-3\.13\.0-32-generic$";
   "^.*-kernel-3\.13\.0-48-generic$";

Comment: The `01autoremove-kernels` only contains the last 2 or 3 kernel packages. When you install another one, the first one in the list is removed from the file making it prone to auto removal.

Comment: As for he patterns: `"^foo.*$"` is the same as `"^foo"`. `^` matches only the start of the string. `.*$` many "any character until the end of the string" but this is only necessary when the code requires a full match. Looking at other patterns in the apt config, `"^foo"` should work.

Comment: I think I understand it now. Thank you for all your help and patience.

Comment: I tried creating the file as you suggested (see my edit of the original question), but Ubuntu still only keeps the 2 latest kernels. Did I misunderstand what you meant?

Comment: @jbang: You need to use `.*` for "match any characters". Note the `.` (dot) which means "any character" while `*` just means "any number of the previous character". So what you wrote only matches `linux-image-----------------generic`

Comment: Oh! It's regular expressions, not file wild cards. I didn't realize that. Thank you. :-)